# Apollo not fetching unless fetchPolicy is set to no-cache

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo

So we have an app built in react-native and node(and graphql)
We encountered some problems, we saw that, some of our queries won't run unless the `fetchPolicy` is set explicitly to `no-cache`(In `react-apollo`), no others, not even `cache-and-network`. Has anyone encountered this before, I looked at the GitHub issues and couldn't find anything really.

Comment: Are you sure that a network request wasn't made with `cache-and-network`? Even on this fetch policy though, if all the data is found on our cache is found it will be used instead, although the network request will still be made in order to maintain the cache updated if necessary.
See more details about the different fetch policies here: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-hoc/#optionsfetchpolicy